# List view error "Filter Value is not in a supported date format"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, view, list-view-web-part

I've column "Name = Order Status","Type = Calculated" & Data Type = "Date and Time". I've given this Condition in the formula:- =IF(NOT([PO Date]=0),"ORDERED","NOT ORDERED"). I'm trying to create view for this column but its getting error while create the view "Filter Value is not in a supported date format".

Same error I'm getting for column "Name = Status","Type = Calculated" & Data Type = "Number". I've given this Condition in the formula:- =IF([PO Date]="","",IF(NOT([Balance Qty]=0),"OPEN","CLOSED"))

Please advice. [image]

Comment: what are column types?

Comment: I've added the question in details.Please have a look.

Comment: In [PO Date]="" expression You want to check if column is blank/empty?

Comment: Yes, Here I'm checking If PO Date entry is blank/empty then "Order Status" = NOT ORDERED and "Status" = nill. OR If PO Date entry is entered (Date) then "Order Status" = ORDERED and "Status" = OPEN/CLOSED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if column is empty with `ISBLANK()` function:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([PO Date]),"NOT ORDERED","ORDERED")
```

I recommend you test your formula in Excel first, because SharePoint uses Excel engine for calculated columns and validation rules.
And here nice article about formulas in SharePoint:

http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/09/20/sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/